# Injecting custom service into ui-router config throws error: Unknown provider: [Service]

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-ui-router

I would like to inject my custom service into angular app in ui-router config function. So I'm defining router as below, but when trying to $inject service I get error: Unknown provider: Auth. Here is code sample:

```
 'use strict';

  angular.module('app.project').config(config);

  // This throws error Unknown provider: Auth
  // config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', 'Auth'];

  // This works, but Auth is of course undefined.
  config.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

  function config($stateProvider, Auth) {
     console.log(Auth);

     $stateProvider.state('default', {
       url: '/',
       template: `<div>default page. </div>
                  <a ui-sref="default">default</a><br>
                  <a ui-sref="projects">projects</a>`,
       data: {
         authorizedRoles: ['admin', 'editor']
       }
     });

  }
```

Here is working examlpe of the app on plunker:
https://embed.plnkr.co/yIGMLCdOIHsB945NsHDl/

I think I'm injecting that in correct way. Changing code to use "iife" won't change anything (I've checked that already).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module:

> Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations
>   and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected
>   into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation
>   of services before they have been fully configured.

In order to be able to inject a service to a configuration, it needs to be written using the provider pattern:

```
angular.module('app.main')
  .service('AuthProvider', function AuthProvider() {
    this.$get = ['$http', function factory($http) {
      return new AuthService($http);
    }];
  });

function AuthService($http) {

(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)</sup>

Services can only be injected during the AngularJS `run` phase, or in `resolver` functions:

**Code**

```
//function config($stateProvider, Auth) {
function config($stateProvider) {
     $stateProvider.state('default', {
         url: '/',
         template: '<div>default page.'+
                    '<a ui-sref="default">default</a><br>'+
                    '<a ui-sref="projects">projects</a>'+
                  '</div>',
         data: {
             authorizedRoles: ['admin', 'editor']
         },
         //INJECT services in resolve functions
         resolve: {
             role: ["Auth", "$q", function(Auth, $q) {
                 return Auth.getUser().then(function(user) {
                     return user.role;
                 }).catch(function(error) {
                     return $q.reject(error);
                 });
            }]
         }
     });
}
```

Because resolver functions are stored and only invoked when the state attempts to load, it is possible to inject services at that time.